# MySQL database disappear

Tags: mysql, database

I have done an idiot mistake, i `cut` the database folder  in `/var/lib/mysql` folder and `paste` into my external hard drive because my hard disk was almost full.

Now i copy the database folder back into the original mysql folder, i cannot access the database anymore, phpmyadmin says it is an empty database.

Is there any way to recover the old database? If it disappear permanently it will be a big pain for me

Comment: Check 'data' folder inside mysql there are databases and all data

Comment: hi quarry, there is no 'data' folder in /var/lib/mysql' :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the engine for your tables? InnoDB or MyISAM? If it is MyISAM then yes they can be recovered if you still have all the files but if type is InnoDB then there might be some trouble

And after pasting the files back to original directory you have to restart mysql server too.

Comment: the table is MyISAM, wow, i feel lucky when i read your answer. Could you tell me what to do to recover it?

Comment: is restarting apache2 the same with restarting mysql server? should i restart my computer? (Since i'm running a long running script so i need to wait until it finishes (some hours later)

Comment: First of all check for following

1) Have you placed the files back in correct dir? your directory should be named same as your database name.
2) Restarting mysql is separate from restarting apache. You can restart it via either
service mysqld restart
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart

or if you are on windows (which might not be the case, as you said dir was /var/lib/mysql, then you can restart from Services). And yes restarting computer should do.

if your database was named test then you should restore the files in
/var/lib/mysql/test/

Comment: After restarting my computer, i can no longer accessing mysql, in phpmyadmin it says `#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server` This link describes a similar problem, but i am using ubuntu 12.04, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584506/ubuntu-11-04-2002-cannot-log-in-to-the-mysql-server. I dare not following the instruction in that link because i'm scared that many other databases will be erased. Could you please help me :-((

Comment: Don't worry. As long as no file was deleted we should be able to recover your database. First of all check if mysql server is running? maybe mysql service did not start after your reboot

Comment: yeah, you are right, it didn't run, now i can run it normally. Thank you!

Comment: Cheers, glad you got it going. As long as files are there there is mostly a way out

Comment: Hi Hanky Panky, i'm sorry, i have sorted out the mysql running problem only. After i got it running normally, i still don't see the tables in my database. I didn't delete any files in the database folder. Is there any way to solve this problem :(

Comment: when i use command `show tables;` from terminal, it says `ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of './productbumbum/' (errno: 13)`

Comment: OK, it is a permission problem. It seems i have resolved following this article http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-error-1018-hy000-cant-read-dir-of-dbname-errno-13/. Many thanks to you :-). So happy

Comment: Great! Glad you got your database back